# Selecting a form's information when we have multiple forms with same ids in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have multiple forms on the html page with same ID. 

I want to send forms information to the server which user selected .I also searched a lot about this and couldn't find anything related.

for my Authorization policy i need to send request with bearer header

my problem is when i submit form 2 my js code send form 1 value 

i cant use specific id for each of my form because i have a lot of forms

**how can i do that???**

P.S. I'd gladly delete the question if there's any duplicate in all SO forums.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var InputNumber = document.querySelectorAll('input[id=InputNumberNewMenu]');
  for (i = 0; i < InputNumber.length; i++) {
    if (InputNumber[i].value !== "") {
      var InputName = InputNumber[i].value;
    }
  }
  var InputDate = document.querySelector('input[id=InputDate]').value;
  var RestaurantId = document.querySelector('input[id=RestaurantId]').value;
  var foodId = document.querySelector('input[id=foodId]').value;
  var address = document.querySelector('input[id=address]:checked').value;
  var token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  var getUrl = window.location;
  var baseUrl = getUrl.protocol + "//" + getUrl.host + "/" + getUrl.pathname.split('/')[0];
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: baseUrl + '/api/order/add',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
      number: InputName,
      restaurant_id: RestaurantId,
      food_id: foodId,
      order_date: InputDate,
      address: address
    }),
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var ipg = data.data.url;
      window.location.replace(ipg);
    },
    error: function(data) {

    }
  });
}
```

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" style="text-align: center">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="InputNumberNewMenu" style="margin-top: 8px">number</label>
    <div class="row" style="display: flex;direction: ltr;justify-content: center;">
      <div class="value-button" id="decrease" onclick="decreaseValue()" value="Decrease Value">-</div>
      <input type="number" id="InputNumberNewMenu" value="1" />
      <div class="value-button" id="increase" onclick="increaseValue()" value="Increase Value">+</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="address">address:</label>
    <input type="radio" id="address" name="address" value="1" required> address1 <br>
    <input type="radio" id="address" name="address" value="2" required> address2 <br>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="InputDate" value="2018-12-16">
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="RestaurantId" name="restaurant_id" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="foodId" name="food_id" value="1">
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-primary">submit </button>
</form>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" style="text-align: center">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="InputNumberNewMenu" style="margin-top: 8px">number</label>
    <div class="row" style="display: flex;direction: ltr;justify-content: center;">
      <div class="value-button" id="decrease" onclick="decreaseValue()" value="Decrease Value">-</div>
      <input type="number" id="InputNumberNewMenu" value="1" />
      <div class="value-button" id="increase" onclick="increaseValue()" value="Increase Value">+</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="address">address:</label>
    <input type="radio" id="address" name="address" value="1" required> address1 <br>
    <input type="radio" id="address" name="address" value="2" required> address2 <br>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="InputDate" value="2018-12-16">
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="RestaurantId" name="restaurant_id" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="foodId" name="food_id" value="2">
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-primary">submit </button>
</form>
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: Per j08691 the fundamental issue here is duplicate IDs. Suggest you use a naming convention eg frmOneAddress

Comment: i generate form with for loop 
and i have new in js 
how i can send request to server side

Comment: If you are generating it with a for loop. Append the value of the iterator (i in your case) to the id. Something like id="form-"+i. So each form will have a unique id like form-1, form-2 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID has to be unique for each single element you should use something else instead of IDs.

#### Use from's `onsubmit` event

```html
<form onsubmit="myFunction">...</form>
```

```js
function myFunction(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  var form = event.target

  // define your input data
  var input1 = $(form).find('[name=input1]').val()

  $.ajax(url, { /* your ajax setup */ })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute

> ... unique identifier (ID)

So. In your code, you have to change IDs

```
<input type="radio" id="address" name="address" value="1" required>  address1 <br>
<input type="radio" id="address" name="address" value="2" required>  address2
```

to

```
<input type="radio" id="address1" name="address" value="1" required>  address1 <br>
<input type="radio" id="address2" name="address" value="2" required>  address2
```

Same with forms' ids, like "address-form", "data-form" or "something-else-form" (or camelCase, as you want). And in your javascript code to get them with it's real and unique ID.

ID used to get right acces to element. If you have a few elements that you have to get access to, use classes or different IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the id's as unique JavaScript function parameter values:

```
decreaseValue(${food_id[0]})
```